# How to use the video datastreaming I get from nginx server?

Tags: opencv, nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, pyffmpeg

I have three nodes in my network:
dataServer --- node1 --- node2.
My video data "friends.mp4" is saved on dataServer. I started both dataServer and node2 as rtmp-nginx servers. I use ffmpeg on node1 to pull datastreaming on dataServerand and push the converted datastreaming to the application "live" on node2.
Here's my configuration of nginx.conf for node2.

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

rtmp {
    server {

    listen 1935;

    chunk_size 4000;

application play {
        play /usr/local/nginx/html/play;
    }

application hls {
        live on;
        hls on;
        hls_path /usr/local/nginx/html/hls;
    hls_fragment 1s;
    hls_playlist_length 4s;
    }

application live  
    {
        live on; 
    allow play all;
    }
}
}
```

I want to run this python code to recognize the faces in friends.mp4:
import cv2

```
vid_capture=cv2.VideoCapture("rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live")
face_detect = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
if (vid_capture.isOpened() == False):
    print("Error opening the video file")
else:
    fps = vid_capture.get(5)
    print("Frames per second : ", fps,'FPS')
    frame_count = vid_capture.get(7)
    print('Frame count : ', frame_count)

while(vid_capture.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = vid_capture.read()
    if ret == True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        face_zone = face_detect.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=3)
        for x, y, w, h in face_zone:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, pt1 = (x, y), pt2 = (x+w, y+h), color = [0,0,255], thickness=2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center = (x + w//2, y + h//2), radius = w//2, color = [0,255,0], thickness = 2)
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(50)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
vid_capture.release()
cv2.destoryAllWindows()
```

But I can't do it because cv2.VideoCapture can not get the data streaming from "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live". Maybe it is because this path is not a file. How can I get the video streaming received by the nginx server and put it to my openCV model? Is there a way that I just access the dataStreaming received by the niginx server and make it a python object that openCV can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the file to a live stream, then use cv2 to process the stream:

```
DataServer --> Node1(FFmpeg MP4 to RTMP) --> Node2(Media Server)
Node2 ---> Node1(cv2 process RTMP)
```

For Node1, you could run command like:

```
ffmpeg -re -i friends.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://node2/live/livestream
```

Then you got a RTMP stream and process it on Node1 again:

```
cv2.VideoCapture("rtmp://node2:1935/live/livestream")
```

Please note that the RTMP is not on node1, so you should never use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for cv to consume it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you tell me while node2 receives the video streaming on the rtmp server, how to send the streaming out on node2 to node1? I'm really suggled at redirecting the streaming out.

Comment: Can I use "push" like this: application live {
        live on;;
       push rtmp://node1:1935/live;
}

Comment: Yes, I tried push and it works. But I'm still not sure how node1 get the datastreaming that node2 sends to node1 by cv2? I know that node1 can get the datastreaming from a file by the method VideoCapture. I looked into the official doc of cv2 and it said VideoCapture() can take a string standing for a file or a number (eg, 0 for the loacal camera). Though VideoCapture() gets a video streaming, the input should be a file. I think I can not get the streaming directly by VideoCapture(). Thank you for your help, again!